# How to organize todo priorities as columns in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm looking at using emacs org mode to have a todo list for myself. I would like to write my todo items with priorities  and generate a table with the number of different priorities. For e.g if I have urgent important later as 3 priorities then have three columns with those values and todo items under them. Please don't recommend an app, if this can be done via writing code in elisp, I would want to do that.

Comment: You can have a look at org-collector.el, which lets you display a headline properties within a table.

Comment: Could you post an example of how you want the table to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bzg said, you can check out [org-collector.el](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-collector.html)

It lets you use elisp expressions for the columns so all you need to do is extract the priorities I think using an org-mode function.